# Ant javac source directory not working

Tags: java, ant, build-process

I have an Apache Ant build file for a java project that contains a javac command to compile my source code. This project has some particular constraints and it is is composed by small sub-projects. Most of these sub-projects have the following folder structure:

```
/docroot
----/WEB-INF
--------/lib
--------/src
-----------A.java
----------- ... (more java classes)
--------/service
-----------B.java
----------- ... (more java classes)
```

Both src and service are source folders. A.java imports some classes that are in the /service folder, for example B.java. In eclipse everything works fine, A.java imports B.java without any error or problem, so I assume that classpath is right. If I run the javac command from Ant, when he tries to compile A.java it gives me an error saying:

> cannot find symbol B.java

In my javac command I'm setting a single source directory = docroot/WEB-INF/src. It works if I also set the docroot/WEB-INF/service as a source directory. But here's the problem of this solution: Some sub-projects only have a single source folder, "docroot/WEB-INF/src". This means that if I set two source directories for the javac command, for the projects with a single source directory "docroot/WEB-INF/src", it will throw an error saying that the sub-project has no folder "docroot/WEB-INF/service".

How can I solve this problem?

```
<antcall target="compile-java">
    <param name="javac.classpathref" value="plugin.classpath" />
    <param name="javac.destdir" value="docroot/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <param name="javac.srcdir" value="docroot/WEB-INF/src" />
    <reference refid="plugin-lib.classpath" torefid="plugin-lib.classpath" />
</antcall>

<target name="compile-java">
    <javac
        classpathref="${javac.classpathref}"
        compiler="${javac.compiler}"
        debug="${javac.debug}"
        deprecation="${javac.deprecation}"
        destdir="${javac.destdir}"
        fork="${javac.fork}"
        includeAntRuntime="false"
        memoryMaximumSize="${javac.memoryMaximumSize}"
        nowarn="${javac.nowarn}"
        encoding="${javac.encoding}"
    >       
        <src path="${javac.srcdir}"/>
    </javac>

    <copy todir="${javac.destdir}">
       <fileset dir="${javac.srcdir}" excludes="**/*.java" />
    </copy>     
</target>
```

Comment: Post your `build.xml` file.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing here, but one thing I can say with absolute certainty: you do not put source files inside the WEB-INF folder. That directory is intended for deployables (jar files in /lib, class files in /class, configuration files in WEB-INF itself) only.

Comment: @hmjd Do you want a specific target from the build file? Because my build file has hundreds of lines. And the whole Ant process is composed by diferente build-files..

Comment: @Gimby I see what you are telling me, but this project is an extension of a known software, and it obeys to the recomended structure...

Comment: @PauloRodrigues, suggest creating a small `build.xml` containing the necessary elements for the `javac` command. You may as result of creating the smaller build file discover the problem yourself.

Comment: @hmjd I've updated the main post with the javac command and the target that launches it.

Comment: The ant docs discuss multiple source directories.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, and I know how to specify multiple source directories. The problem is for the sub-projects that only have one source directory. Specifying multiple source directories would cause an error when compiling this sub-projects.

Comment: Try the 'srcdir' attribute instead of nested 'src' element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<src path="${javac.srcdir}"/>
```

means that `${javac.srcdir}` is interpreted as a *path* (colon- or semicolon-separated depending on your platform) rather than a single directory.  So you could provide more than one directory in here.

```
<path id="module.srcdir.path">
  <pathelement location="docroot/WEB-INF/src" />
  <pathelement location="docroot/WEB-INF/services" />
</path>
<property name="module.srcdir" refid="module.srcdir.path" />

<antcall target="compile-java">
    <param name="javac.classpathref" value="plugin.classpath" />
    <param name="javac.destdir" value="docroot/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <param name="javac.srcdir" value="${module.srcdir}" />
    <reference refid="plugin-lib.classpath" torefid="plugin-lib.classpath" />
</antcall>
```

Comment: thanks for your response in advance. I know that I can do that, or even specify the paths separated by :, like path1:path2. But if I do that, when compiling the sub-projects that do not have 2 source directories, ant throws an error saying that one of the directories doesn't exist.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues sorry, I understood it as `compile-java` being the generic target and the `antcall` being for this specific sub-module.

Answer (score 0):

For now I found a solution. I created a separated build file for each sub-project that needs two source directories to compile. In it I override the javac command to set the necessary source directories for each specific case. This way the "regular" javac command will still execute with a single source to be compatible with the sub-projects that only need one source directory.